# Rewrite url in reverse proxy in golang

Tags: http, character-encoding, reverse-proxy

i have a problem with send a special char in url by reverse proxy in golang. This is my function:

```
func TurnOnDevice(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        API_TURN_ON := "/relay/0?turn=on"

    fmt.Println("Turn on", MapDevice[device])
    /* Modify url request */
    fmt.Println(r.URL.Path)
    r.URL.Path = ""
        
    //rewriteRequestURL(r, r.URL)
    /* Proxy http request */
    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(&url.URL{
        Scheme: "http",
        Host:   "localhost:8081",
        Path:   API_TURN_ON,
    })

    proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)

    return
}
```

The complete url is http://localhost:8081/relay/0?turn=on. If i see the wireshark trace i found the following http request: http://localhost:8080/relay/0%3Fturn=on/. For my project is a problem send %3F. This is a encoding of '?'. Is there a solution for send '?' instead %3F.

Thanks

I tried to write a reverse proxy in golang. I necessity to send special char '?'